# What type of lubricant should be used on oven door hinges?

Tags: maintenance

My oven has squeaky door hinges.

There are many types of lubricant available ( traditional, silicon, Teflon etc.), all with different pros/cons.

I'm curious, is there a "best practice" choice for what should be used in this case?

Comment: I would suggest closing this and asking it on http://diy.stackexchange.com for better answers.

Comment: ask the oven maker ?

Comment: @GdD I considered that, and will if a good answer doesn't come here. However, I believe that given how specific a question it is, a better answer should come here, where there will be people more familiar with the requirements.

Comment: My go-to is WD-40 (in the US), particularly for its penetrating and water-displacing properties.

Comment: WD-40 is good for getting things un-stuck @Dorothy, but it dries out quickly so it's not a good long-term solution.

Comment: I'd recommend White Lithium Grease.  My browser has fritzed on me, so I can't copy/paste links.  According to Wikipedia, it exhibits "good temperature tolerance" and is commonly used in automotive applications.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ will white lithium grease be suitable for use in a kitchen? Specifically, does it have a level of toxicity (compared to other options) that might make it inadvisable?

Comment: @Niall - The articles I've seen on this have no specific warning of toxicity apart from [this](https://www.addl.purdue.edu/newsletters/1991/lithium.shtml) one which indicates a low risk of toxicity to cattle.  Since most oven hinges are on the outside of the "hot box", I'd say the risk is very minimal.

Answer (score 6):

Although they don't get as hot as the interior of the oven oven hinges are exposed to a significant amount of heat, so you should pick a lubricant which isn't going to burst into flames when exposed to heat, dry out, or gum up. My usual go-to oil for the home is 3 in 1 oil, but I wouldn't use it here because of the heat. 3 in 1 make a high performance spray lubricant which handles high temperatures, sprayon make a food-grade high temperature lubricant spray, and you can also get spray on bearing lube (for cars but is good for high temperature) - all of which would be fine for this application.

I would recommend a spray on lube because oven hinges tend to be hard to access, and the spray will help force it in better, however if you gave good access you could get a tube instead.

Comment: I could be quite tempted to use a PTFE bike chain lube.

Comment: Thanks GdH, you've brought up some useful things to consider here and given good advice. I'm afraid though that it doesn't address the main thrust of the question - what kind of formulation is best, rather than the medium of application.